# iPhone simulator writes to socket fine - but not iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios-simulator

Despite working earlier, my socket chat app now refuses to write to socket on the iPhone!
It works fine on the simulator and again, used to run fine on my phone.  I don't really know where to start troubleshooting this issue --- just seems weird.  My server doesn't detect anything trying to connect.
Any ideas on how to start troubleshooting this?
Thanks tons.

Comment: Probably a permissions problem. Impossible to tell without teh codez.

Answer (score 1):

I did run into a problem where using sockets on the iPhone would not open up the cell phone network unless something else opened it first.  I had to run an http call to a generic web site first, and then the sockets would communicate normally.  Try putting a call, like sendSynchronousRequest, to a generic web site, like www.apple.com, before opening your socket, and see if it works in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I need to stop wasting all you nice peoples' time.

Long story, my friend updated to iOS 5.1.  Now the 3G network reads 4G on iOS 5.1.  So I turned off my (5.0) wifi to see if mine cell network was "4G" (which, of course, it wasn't).

But yeah, having turned off wifi my app could no longer join my locally hosted server...

I grabbed Charles though, and it looks handy, so thanks for that anyways.  Also Owen's comment about the cell network originally made me think about checking my wifi, as my app shouldn't even be using the cell network yet.  But I'll keep in mind what you said for the future.

Thanks everybody!

Comment: Please indicate that your question is answered